# Accessing a private GKE cluster via Cloud VPN

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-vpn

We have setup a GKE cluster using Terraform with private and shared networking:

Network configuration:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "int_kube02" {
  name          = "int-kube02"
  region        = var.region
  project       = "infrastructure"
  network       = "projects/infrastructure/global/networks/net-10-23-0-0-16"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.23.5.0/24"
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "pods"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.60.0.0/14" # 10.60 - 10.63
  }
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "services"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.56.0.0/16"
  }
}
```

Cluster configuration:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "gke_kube02" {
  name     = "kube02"
  location = var.region

  initial_node_count = var.gke_kube02_num_nodes

  network    = "projects/ninfrastructure/global/networks/net-10-23-0-0-16"
  subnetwork = "projects/infrastructure/regions/europe-west3/subnetworks/int-kube02"

  master_authorized_networks_config {
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "admin vpn"
      cidr_block   = "10.42.255.0/24"
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "monitoring server"
      cidr_block   = "10.42.4.33/32"
    }
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "cluster nodes"
      cidr_block   = "10.23.5.0/24"
    }
  }

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = "pods"
    services_secondary_range_name = "services"
  }

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes    = true
    enable_private_endpoint = true
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "192.168.23.0/28"


  }

  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-highcpu-2"

    tags = ["kube-no-external-ip"]
    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = true
    }

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]
  }
}
```

The cluster is online and running fine. If I connect to one of the worker nodes i can reach the api using `curl`:

```
curl -k https://192.168.23.2
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

I also see a healthy cluster when using a SSH port forward:

```
❯ k get pods --all-namespaces --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
NAMESPACE     NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   event-exporter-gke-5479fd58c8-mv24r                2/2     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   fluentbit-gke-ckkwh                                2/2     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   fluentbit-gke-lblkz                                2/2     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   fluentbit-gke-zglv2                                2/2     Running   4          4h44m
kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-j72d9                            1/1     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-ttrzk                            1/1     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   gke-metrics-agent-wbqgc                            1/1     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   kube-dns-697dc8fc8b-rbf5b                          4/4     Running   5          4h44m
kube-system   kube-dns-697dc8fc8b-vnqb4                          4/4     Running   1          4h44m
kube-system   kube-dns-autoscaler-844c9d9448-f6sqw               1/1     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-kube02-default-pool-2bf58182-xgp7   1/1     Running   0          4h43m
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-kube02-default-pool-707f5d51-s4xw   1/1     Running   0          4h43m
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-kube02-default-pool-bd2c130d-c67h   1/1     Running   0          4h43m
kube-system   l7-default-backend-6654b9bccb-mw6bp                1/1     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   metrics-server-v0.4.4-857776bc9c-sq9kd             2/2     Running   0          4h43m
kube-system   pdcsi-node-5zlb7                                   2/2     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   pdcsi-node-kn2zb                                   2/2     Running   0          4h44m
kube-system   pdcsi-node-swhp9                                   2/2     Running   0          4h44m
```

So far so good. Then I setup the Cloud Router to announce the `192.168.23.0/28` network. This was successful and replicated to our local site using BGP. Running `show route 192.168.23.2` displays the correct route is advertised and installed.

When trying to reach the API from the monitoring server `10.42.4.33` I just run into timeouts. All three, the Cloud VPN, the Cloud Router and the Kubernetes Cluster run in `europe-west3`.

When i try to ping one of the workers its working completely fine, so networking in general works:

```
[me@monitoring ~]$ ping 10.23.5.216
PING 10.23.5.216 (10.23.5.216) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.23.5.216: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=8.21 ms
64 bytes from 10.23.5.216: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=7.70 ms
64 bytes from 10.23.5.216: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=5.41 ms
64 bytes from 10.23.5.216: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=7.98 ms
```

Googles [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters) gives no hit what could be missing. From what I understand the Cluster API should be reachable by now.

What could be missing and why is the API not reachable via VPN?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this part of the documentation you shared? https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cp-on-prem-routing. Also please provide the Cloud VPN and Cloud Router configurations taking out any sensitive information

Comment: Most likely you have not enabled exporting custom routes from the peering connection.  You'll see it as one of the steps in the link posted in the comment by  @GabrielRobledoAhumada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been missing the peering configuration documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cp-on-prem-routing

```
resource "google_compute_network_peering_routes_config" "peer_kube02" {
  peering = google_container_cluster.gke_kube02.private_cluster_config[0].peering_name
  project = "infrastructure"
  network = "net-10-13-0-0-16"

  export_custom_routes = true
  import_custom_routes = false
}
```